# Looping through home listings with Selenium

Tags: selenium, pagination

I am trying to loop through a home listings site with Selenium and am having trouble getting the while loop to loop through the pages.
[The pages present on the web page as shown, with no "Previous" or "Next" button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvWiR.png)
I'm not sure how to find the total of number of pages of listings for the site, but was testing this while loop with 20 (seen with max_page_count = 20), as I know there are at least 20 pages of listings. I am considering two (2) ways of iterating through the pages, but am stuck at different stages with each:

1. use: https://www.tinyhomebuilders.com/tiny-house-marketplace/search?page={}.format(page) and create a counter to go through the pages.
2. use the click function with Selenium to click on the page element shown in the picture provided.

I've checked and know I'm able to scrape the price element off the page, but am finding that the click function is not working.

Here is my code:

```
driver_location = 'C:/Users/oefel/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64'
os.environ['webdriver.firefox.driver'] = driver_location 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(driver_location)
driver.get("https://www.tinyhomebuilders.com/tiny-house-marketplace/search")
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.maximize_window()

tiny_house_price = []

page_count = 0
max_page_count = 20

while (page_count < max_page_count):
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

        scraped_price = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-body > div.price")
        for price in scraped_price:
                tiny_house_price.append(price.text)
        print(tiny_house_price)

        page = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.pagination > li > a.href').click()

        page_count += 1
```

I would so appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium to get the text in this case. You can get the page text by making a get request to the page and getting the html from it. The page number is being passed as a URL parameter and you can just loop through it and get the required output. Sample below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tiny_house_price = []

page_count = 1
max_page_count = 20

while (page_count < max_page_count):
    r = requests.get('https://www.tinyhomebuilders.com/tiny-house-marketplace/search?page={}'.format(page_count))
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    scraped_price = html_soup.select("div.card-body > div.price")
    for price in scraped_price:
        tiny_house_price.append(price.text.strip())
    print(tiny_house_price)

    page_count += 1
```

The click in your case is not working as the selector is not correct. You will have to find the element by link text and click. The link text would be the page count.

The same page url parameter logic used above can be used in case you want to use selenium too. You just need to open the web page using selenium and get the source and navigate to the new page after you get the html.